# SwiftUI. NavigationView nested button

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a view with a list. If I choose one of the rows, I can move to the detail view. But there is a problem. In the list view I am using the NavigationView to jump to the detail view through the NavigationLink. There is a back button in the detail view and I want to set there an another button to an another view where I can add some data. But there is a problem. I see back button, but there is no button to view where I can add data. I know it is related to NavigationView but I don't know how to solve it. I removed NavigationView from the detail view but stil I can't set button to another view in the NavigationBar.

DataView (Detail view):
As you can see the button is no in the NavigationBar. I want to set it in same line as the Vehicle back button.

[image]

StartView (List view):

```
import SwiftUI

struct StartView: View {

@ObservedObject var viewModel: StartViewModel
var addVehicleViewModel: AddVehicleViewModel
@State var showSheetView = false

var body: some View {
   
    NavigationView {
        
        List(viewModel.vehicles) { vehicle in
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(vehicle: vehicle)) {
                StartRow(vehicle: vehicle)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Vehicles")
        .onAppear(perform: {
            UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
            self.viewModel.fetchVehicles()
        })
    .navigationBarItems(trailing:
        Button(action: {
            self.showSheetView.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text("+").font(.system(size: 43))
        })
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheetView) {
                AddVehicleView(viewModel: self.addVehicleViewModel)
        }
        )
    }
    
}
}
```

DataView (Detail view - there is a TabView and this is the reason of different name):

```
import SwiftUI

struct DataView: View {

var vehicle: Vehicle
@State var showSheetView = false

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView {
    VStack() {
        Color.red
        Button(action: {
                       self.showSheetView.toggle()
            print("DataView TAPPED")
                   }, label: {
                       Text("+").font(.system(size: 43))
                   })
                       .sheet(isPresented: $showSheetView) {
                           RefuelingListView()
                   }
    }
}
    .navigationBarTitle(vehicle.model)
}
}
```

Comment: So, you want another button at right side of Back button?

Comment: This is what I want to do.